# When does a variable or function defined in a namespace is allocated memory?

Tags: c++, memory, namespaces

Consider the code:

```
namespace Jack
{
    char ch{'A'};
    void show(){ std::cout<<ch };
}
int main()
{
Jack::show();
return 0;
}
```

When was the memory allocated to `Jack::ch` in this case? During the time of declaration of the namespace `Jack` or at the statement `Jack::show()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ch` object is in the global scope. Instances of classes/types in the global scope get constructed, initialized, allocated, whatever, at startup, and their scope exist for the lifetime of the execution.

An object's namespace only relates to the name of the object. The object's construction or destruction is not affected by any namespace the name of the object is in, but by its scope.